# Node.js server outgoing http request logging format

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I have nodejs server, and need to implement logging of outgoing requests.

Let's say I use node-request

```
const np = require('request-promise');
const logger = require('./winston-logger');

np.get('https://swapi.co/api/planets').
  .then(res => {
    logger.info( ??? )
  })
  .catch(err => {
    logger.error(err);
  })
```

My question what should I put in logger.info? Requested url, headers, response body? Is there popular and established by most devs format?

I was looking into this and didn't find sufficient solution.
There is apache log format. But is that what is the best for nodejs apps? For example there is no time-response for request, what could be useful to log. And how it well working with winston logger?
Also, I think this format should be well recognizable for logs parsers

Any thoughts how you approach logging for nodejs?

Comment: so your main problem is that how do you do request logs.

Comment: @Dipakchavda, for now it's only format of logging. I can use interceptors or other library to log outgoing request. But I'm struggling to find out what should I log

Comment: ok so in logging basically you should logs url, time to executes, methods , status and querystring in case of get and http body paratmeters in case of post.

Comment: no do you get my point or still confuse?

Comment: yeah, I've got your point. That's roughly what I thought I need to do. Just confused, that there is no established format for it. Like you have to log url, headers, response-time, status, method in this order separated let say by spaces or '|'. Not necessary  strict rules, but at least best practices.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to give you an answer with some dummy piece of code. I specifically used Winston for an application logging purpose.

In Winston, you may also define custom log parameters as well as json format or plain text format. Definitely, in the sample code, I did not use 
request or request-promise module but it well enough to get an idea that how Winston configure and used in an application.

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "winston",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.16.2",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "nodemon": "1.15.1",
    "winston": "2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

> logger.js

```
var winston = require('winston');
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({
      filename: __dirname + '/logger.log',
      json: false,
      timestamp: function () {
        return new Date()
      },
      handleExceptions: true,
      humanReadableUnhandledException: true,
    })
  ],
  exceptionHandlers: [
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: __dirname + '/exceptions.log', json: false })
  ],
  exitOnError: false
});
module.exports = logger;
module.exports.stream = {
  write: function (message, encoding) {
    logger.info(message);
  }
};
```

> index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const logger = require("./logger");

app.listen(3000, () => {
  logger.log("info", 'Example app listening on port 3000!');
  const data = require("./data")(app);
});
```

> data.js

const logger = require("./logger");
logger.log("info", 'executes data.js');

```
module.exports = ((app) => {

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        logger.log("info", "Default route executes");
        res.send("hello world from data file");
    });

    app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
        logger.log("info", "hello route executes");
        res.send("hello route executes");
    });

    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        logger.log("info", "error routing called");
        logger.log("error", err);
        if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
            res.status(401).json({ status: 0, code: 401, type: "unauthorised", message: err.name + ": " + err.message });
        } else {
            res.status(404).json({ status: 0, code: 404, type: "ENOENT", message: "file not found" });
        }
    });
    return app;
});
```